# Decode JSON into a target struct which differs from the JSON model

Tags: swift

I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "header":{
    "namespace":"Device",
    "name":"Response",
    "messageID":"60FA815A-DC432316",
    "payloadVersion":"1"
  },
  "payload":{
    "device":{
      "firmware":"1.23W",
      "name":"Device 1",
      "uuid":"0ba64a0c-7a88b278-0001",
      "security":{
        "code":"aXdAPqd2OO9sZ6evLKjo2Q=="
      }
    },
    "system":{
      "uptime":5680126
    }
  }
}
```

I created the Swift structs using quicktype.io:

```swift
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let header: Header
    let payload: Payload
}

// MARK: - Header
struct Header: Codable {
    let namespace, name, messageID, payloadVersion: String
}

// MARK: - Payload
struct Payload: Codable {
    let device: Device
    let system: System
}

// MARK: - Device
struct Device: Codable {
    let firmware, name, uuid: String
    let security: Security
}

// MARK: - Security
struct Security: Codable {
    let code: String
}

// MARK: - System
struct System: Codable {
    let uptime: Int
}
```

However, I already have a `Device` type, that is a bit more minimal:

```swift
struct Device: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let ip: String
    let name: String
    let firmware: String
    let uptime: Double
    // ...
}
```

How can I nicely decode the raw JSON data into my `Device` struct? Note that my `Device` is flat and has fields, that are more deeply nested in the original API response model. Do I a custom `Decodable` implementation?

Comment: You already asked the exactly same question some 10 hours ago, didn't you?

Comment: No, I did not….

Comment: Okay.  I'm sorry about the accusation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create intermediate CodingKeys, but this often gets pretty tedious and unnecessary. Instead you can make a general-purpose "string-key" like:

```
struct AnyStringKey: CodingKey, Hashable, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    var stringValue: String
    init(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    init<S: StringProtocol>(_ stringValue: S) { self.init(stringValue: String(stringValue)) }
    var intValue: Int?
    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    init(stringLiteral value: String) { self.init(value) }
}
```

With that, you can navigate your structure pretty easily in a single decoder init by decoding nested containers:

```
extension Device: Decodable {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let root = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self)
        let header = try root.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self, forKey: "header")

        self.name = try header.decode(String.self, forKey: "name")

        let payload = try root.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self, forKey: "payload")
        let device = try payload.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self, forKey: "device")

        self.id = try device.decode(UUID.self, forKey: "uuid")
        self.firmware = try device.decode(String.self, forKey: "firmware")

        let system = try payload.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self, forKey: "system")
        self.uptime = try system.decode(Double.self, forKey: "uptime")
    }
}
```

(I skipped `ip` because it's not in your data, and I assumed that your UUID was just a typo since it's not valid.)

With this, you should be able to decode any part you need.

This is very straightforward and standard, but if you have a lot of things to decode it can get a little tedious. You can improve it with a helper function in that case.

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forPath path: String) throws -> T
    where T : Decodable, Key == AnyStringKey {
        let components = path.split(separator: ".")
        guard !components.isEmpty else {
            throw DecodingError.keyNotFound(AnyStringKey(path),
                                            .init(codingPath: codingPath,
                                                  debugDescription: "Could not find path \(path)",
                                                  underlyingError: nil))
        }

        if components.count == 1 {
            return try decode(type, forKey: AnyStringKey(components[0]))
        } else {
            let container = try nestedContainer(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self, forKey: AnyStringKey(components[0]))
            return try container.decode(type, forPath: components.dropFirst().joined(separator: "."))
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you can access values by a dotted-path syntax:

```
extension Device: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let root = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyStringKey.self)
        self.name = try root.decode(String.self, forPath: "header.name")
        self.id = try root.decode(UUID.self, forPath: "payload.device.uuid")
        self.firmware = try root.decode(String.self, forPath: "payload.device.firmware")
        self.uptime = try root.decode(Double.self, forPath: "payload.system.uptime")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two quick possible solutions:

#### Solution 1:

Rename the Codable Device:

```
struct Device: Codable {
    ...
}
```

into

```
struct DeviceFromAPI: Codable { 
    ...
}
```

And then replace

```
struct Payload: Codable {
    let device: Device
    ...
}
```

into

```
struct Payload: Codable {
    let device: DeviceFromAPI
    ...
}
```

#### Solution2:

Use nested structures.

Put everything inside `Welcome` (which is the default QuickType.io name by the way, might be interesting to rename it).

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let header: Header
    let payload: Payload

    // MARK: - Header
    struct Header: Codable {
    let namespace, name, messageID, payloadVersion: String
    }
    ...
}
```

Go even if needed to put `Device` in `Payload`.

Then, you just have to use `Welcome.Payload.Device` or `Welcome.Device` (depending on how you nested it) when you want to refer to your Codable Device, and just `Device` when it's your own.

#### Then

Then, just have a custom `init()` for `Device` with the `Codable Device` as a parameter.

```
extension Device {
    init(withCodableDevice codableDevice: DeviceFromAPI) {
        self.firmware = codableDevice.firmware
        ...
    }

}
```

or with solution 2:

```
extension Device {
    init(withCodableDevice codableDevice: Welcome.Payload.Device) {
        self.firmware = codableDevice.firmware
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I think I was a bit unspecific in my initial post and updated it accordingly: Some values I want in my `Device` model are not part of the "API Device" model but for example in the `System` one. While the API response is structured and nested, my model only contains important information in a flat representation.

Comment: Then, instead of making it `init(withCodableDevice codableDevice: Welcome.Payload.Device)`, do `init(withPayload payload: Welcome.Payload)`, and `self.firmware = payload.device.firmware; self.uptime = payload.system.uptime`...